FlatGeobuf bbox not filtering in Leaflet
I use the code sample from https://flatgeobuf.org/examples/leaflet/large.html. My code is following:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => { console.log('THERE');
//////////////////////////////
//map = L.map('map', {
// zoomControl:false, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
//}).fitBounds([[24.69013990167979,121.80364150896582],[24.690963404516896,121.80496755608748]]);
let map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lng], 15);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);
//var hash = new L.Hash(map);
//map.attributionControl.setPrefix('qgis2web · Leaflet · QGIS');
//var autolinker = new Autolinker({truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}});
// remove popup's row if "visible-with-data"
function removeEmptyRowsFromPopupContent(content, feature) {
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = content;
var rows = tempDiv.querySelectorAll('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
var td = rows[i].querySelector('td.visible-with-data');
var key = td ? td.id : '';
if (td && td.classList.contains('visible-with-data') && feature.properties[key] == null) {
rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
}
}
return tempDiv.innerHTML;
}
// add class to format popup if it contains media
function addClassToPopupIfMedia(content, popup) {
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = content;
if (tempDiv.querySelector('td img')) {
popup._contentNode.classList.add('media');
// Delay to force the redraw
setTimeout(function() {
popup.update();
}, 10);
} else {
popup._contentNode.classList.remove('media');
}
}
//var zoomControl = L.control.zoom({
// position: 'topleft'
//}).addTo(map);
//var bounds_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
//var bounds_group1 = new L.featureGroup([]);
//function setBounds() {
//}
//map.createPane('pane_TaiwaneMapnew_0');
//map.getPane('pane_TaiwaneMapnew_0').style.zIndex = -1;
// var layer_TaiwaneMapnew_0 = L.WMS.layer("http://maps.nlsc.gov.tw/S_Maps/wms", "EMAP97", {
// pane: 'pane_TaiwaneMapnew_0',
// format: 'image/png',
// uppercase: true,
// transparent: true,
// continuousWorld : true,
// tiled: true,
// info_format: 'text/html',
// opacity: 1,
// identify: false,
// attribution: '',
//});
//map.addLayer(layer_TaiwaneMapnew_0);
// optionally show some meta-data about the FGB file
function handleHeaderMeta(headerMeta) {
const header = document.getElementById('header')
const formatter = new JSONFormatter(headerMeta, 10)
while (header.firstChild)
header.removeChild(header.firstChild)
header.appendChild(formatter.render())
}

        // For the example, we fix a visible Rect representing the query
        // bounding box in the middle of the map
        function getBoundForRect() {
            //console.log(map.getCenter());
            //const widthMeters = 200;
            //return map.getCenter().toBounds(widthMeters);
            const bounds = map.getBounds();

            const width = map.distance(bounds.getNorthWest(), bounds.getNorthEast());
            const height = map.distance(bounds.getNorthWest(), bounds.getSouthWest());
            return map.getCenter().toBounds(Math.min(width, height) * 0.41);
        }

        // convert the rect into the format flatgeobuf expects
        
  function fgBoundingBox() {
            const bounds = getBoundForRect();
            console.log(bounds);
            return {
                minY: bounds.getSouth(),
                maxY: bounds.getNorth(),
                minX: bounds.getWest(),
                maxX: bounds.getEast(),
            };
        }
        
        bboxObjectToArray = (obj) => [
            [obj.minX, obj.minY],
            [obj.maxX, obj.maxY],
        ];
// show a leaflet rect corresponding to our bounding box
rectangle = L.rectangle(getBoundForRect(), {
interactive: false,
color: "blue",
fillOpacity: 0.1,
opacity: 1.0,
}).addTo(map);
rectangle.bringToFront();
// track the previous results so we can remove them when adding new results
let previousResults = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
async function updateResults() {
// remove the old results
previousResults.remove();
const nextResults = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
previousResults = nextResults;
//console.log(nextResults);

            // Use flatgeobuf JavaScript API to iterate features as geojson.
            // Because we specify a bounding box, flatgeobuf will only fetch the relevant subset of data,
            // rather than the entire file.
            const colorScale = ((d) => {
                //console.log(d);
                return d > 7500 ? '#800026' :
                    d > 5000 ? '#BD0026' :
                    d > 2500  ? '#E31A1C' :
                    d > 1000 ? '#FC4E2A' :
                    d > 500   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                    d > 250  ? '#FEB24C' :
                    d > 100   ? '#FED976' :
                    '#FFEDA0'
            });//console.log(colorScale);
            
            const iter = flatgeobuf.deserialize('data/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb',bboxObjectToArray(fgBoundingBox()),handleHeaderMeta);
            const results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
            //console.log(iter);
            try{
            let i = 0;results1 = { type: "FeatureCollection", features: [] };
            for await(let feature of iter){//console.log("FEATURE:"+feature);
                if(feature!=null){
                results1.features.push({...feature, id: i});
                i+=1;//console.log(i);
                }
                // Leaflet styling
                const defaultStyle = { 
                    color: colorScale(feature.properties["Area"]), 
                    weight: 1, 
                    fillOpacity: 0.4,
                };
                L.geoJSON(feature, {
                    style: defaultStyle,
                }).on({
                    'mouseover': function(e) {
                        const layer = e.target;
                        layer.setStyle({
                            weight: 4,
                            fillOpacity: 0.8,
                        });
                        layer.bringToFront();
                        console.log(layer);
                    },
                    'mouseout': function(e) {
                        const layer = e.target;
                        layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);console.log(layer);
                    }
               }).bindPopup(`${feature.properties["Area"]} people live in this census block.</h1>`).addTo(nextResults);//.bindPopup(`${feature.properties["Area"]} people live in this census block.</h1>`)
            }
            }
            catch(e){console.log(e);return;}
        // if the user is panning around alot, only update once per second max
        updateResults = _.throttle(updateResults, 100);
        }
        // show a leaflet rect corresponding to our bounding box
        //let rectangle = L.rectangle(getBoundForRect(), { color: "blue", fillOpacity: 0.7, opacity: 1.0 }).addTo(map);
        // Render the bounding box rectangle

        //rectangle.bringToFront();
        // show results based on the initial map
        updateResults();
        // ...and update the results whenever the map moves
        map.on("moveend", function(s){
            rectangle.setBounds(getBoundForRect());
            updateResults();
        });

Data is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/s5721ev5tddmakobl3g92/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb?rlkey=dxd6359fmhfa0y151y6wv89b8&st=t691m0ar&dl=0
Sample code gives the right filtering number: 470 features: My code gives me all the features, which is not desirable: 105,014 features
I've checked over n over but still can't figure out why.

You write about "the right filtering number" in your question. Which number is that? When I run the code sample, I don't see this number displayed anywhere. Please edit your question and add info about what is this "the right filtering number" referring to.

Please don't put additional explanations in comments. Rather edit the question and put them there.

@TomazicM, thank you for the heads up, and I've updated my question.

Without access to your data it's impossible to say why it does not work for you.

data link:https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/s5721ev5tddmakobl3g92/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb?rlkey=dxd6359fmhfa0y151y6wv89b8&st=t691m0ar&dl=0

The problem is that CRS of your FlatGeobuf data is not EPSG:4326, but EPSG:3857. This means you have to unproject it to EPSG:4326 when loading feature into GeoJSON layer and project bounding box to EPSG:3857 for getting features from FlatGeobuf data.
Projecting bounding box to EPSG:3857 can be done like this:
function fgBoundingBox() {
  const bounds = getBoundForRect();
  const sw = L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(bounds.getSouthWest());
  const ne = L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(bounds.getNorthEast());
  return {
    minY: sw.y,
    maxY: ne.y,
    minX: sw.x,
    maxX: ne.x,
  };
}

Unprojecting data to EPSG:4326 before loading feature into GeoJSON layer is done with Turf turf.toWgs84 method. Relevant part of the code is:
const iter = flatgeobuf.deserialize('data/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb', fgBoundingBox(), handleHeaderMeta);
  const results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
  try {
    let i = 0;
    results1 = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: []};
    for await(let feature of iter){
      if (feature!=null) {
        results1.features.push({...feature, id: i});
        i+=1;
      }
      const defaultStyle = { 
        color: colorScale(feature.properties["Area"]), 
        weight: 1, 
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
      };
      L.geoJSON(turf.toWgs84(feature), {
        style: defaultStyle,
      }).on({
        'mouseover': function(e) {
          const layer = e.target;
          layer.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
          });
          layer.bringToFront();
        },
        'mouseout': function(e) {
          const layer = e.target;
          layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);console.log(layer);
        }
     }).bindPopup(`${feature.properties["Area"]} people live in this census block.</h1>`).addTo(nextResults);//.bindPopup(`${feature.properties["Area"]} people live in this census block.</h1>`)
    }
  }
  catch(e){console.log(e);return;}
  updateResults = _.throttle(updateResults, 100);
}

This is the result:


thank you so much for pointing out the problem source; however, your code seems not running on my side, the results returns 0:{type: 'FeatureCollection', features: Array(0)}, I wonder is it because fgBoundingBox sequence mapping?

there's a typo 'data/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb.mbtiles', should be 'data/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb'

@Myprofiler Corrected. Not really a typo, I added extension when doing test, since my local server does not now about MIME type .fgb.

So does it finally work for you?

Not really, I use this code with my fgb file. The result is 0, which not filter, if I add bboxtoobjectarray the result is 105,014. After that I use new fgb projected to 4326, the result is 105,014 again. Still not able to get results above…

If you can put your .fgb file somewhere on the web where it can be reached, I can create JSFiddle that will work.

Yes, it can be reached: https://niusil.myqnapcloud.com:8081/barcode/qgis2web1/data/Gy_A_rice_weight_UTMz51_1.fgb

When I try to use it, I get CORS error.

I tried to debug your code at https://niusil.myqnapcloud.com:8081/barcode/qgis2web1/, but there you are using EPSG:4326 for bounding box which is wrong and cannot work.

Should I use code above to project bounding box to EPSG:3826? I tried it but not working.

Yes, then I can debug why it does not work for you.

For some reason Leaflet GeoJSON layer option coordsToLatLng does not work in your code. I changed the approach to unprojecting coordinates to use Turf turf.toWgs84 method. See modified answer.

Thank you, but it's not working still. I use turf.toWgs84 and the results are still 105,014. Should I use projection in fgBoundingBox?

It works for me if I use your code from https://niusil.myqnapcloud.com:8081/barcode/qgis2web1/, I just had to uncomment link to Leaflet JS. I don't know why it does not work for you.

Code from this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tpwkmhb2/ works for me locally if I replace .fgb file address with address from local server. JSFiddle does not work because of CORS error, but code should work if you put it on your server.

Thank you so much! Finally I see bbox filtering features and change accordingly to zoom: https://niusil.myqnapcloud.com:8081/barcode/qgis2web1/index1.html?lat=24.7431988&lng=121.7645923&lnd=00882-0016#20/24.69055/121.80430; however, I can't see base map and I can't figure out why...

After several testing, there appears another issue, I can't use setview to locate lat, lng parameters. Still trying to figure that out, too....

Answer helped you solve the problem from the question, and so it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved. If you have another problem/question, please post it as a new question.

Thank you and I have marked it already!
